# jQuery or JS handling browsers back button

Tags: browser, back-button

Any ideas how to intercept the browser back button via jQuery, so I can run my event function?
I don't need to use jQuery BBQ or jQuery Address, only prevent the default behaviour and run it later after some animate.

Thank you!

d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery land:

```
$(window).unload( function () { /*code here*/ });
```

EDIT- There was a parentheses instead of a close bracket

EDIT - Removed Extra Semicolin

Comment: According to [docs](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) it doesn't specifically intercepts back button but any event that unloads current page. It can be anything clicking on link, forward button or back button based on the browser.

Comment: This is true Mahesha, unload is fired on navigation away from the current page. As far as I know there is no specific event for the 'back' button.

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried but i guess this do what you want.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   // stuff do do before the window is unloaded here.
}
```

with jQuery you could try the .unload() function

> The unload event is sent to the window
>   element when the user navigates away
>   from the page. This could mean one of
>   many things. The user could have
>   clicked on a link to leave the page,
>   or typed in a new URL in the address
>   bar. The forward and back buttons will
>   trigger the event. Closing the browser
>   window will cause the event to be
>   triggered. Even a page reload will
>   first create an unload event.