# Force page reload on browser back when the fragment identifier changes

Tags: asp.net, browser, postback, back-button, fragment-identifier

Problem:

```
1.User clicks on this link: default.aspx#id=1.
2.The page loads, the JS from the page gets the fragment identifier (in this case id=1), and then it posts back and loads some content based on that id.
3.User then clicks on the next link: default.aspx#id=2.
4.Same as 2.
5.User clicks the back button in browser.
6.The url changes back to default.aspx#id=1 but the postback is not fired so the new content from #id=1 is not loaded again. (in other words, the page content is not refreshed)
```

What i need is to somehow reload the page according to #id=1 on back button pressed.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [On - window.location.hash - change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

Comment: Please this link

[Reference link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351392/jquery-or-js-handling-browsers-back-button